# Duplicate var on href Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is the route

```
Route::get('ph/{id}/informe', function ($id) {
  $ph = Ph::find($id);
  return view('ph.informe')->withphs($ph);
});
```

when I print the name in the title I have no problem

```
<p>Informe Confidencial: {{ $phs->name }}</p> =====>  <p>Informe Confidencial: Test1</p>
```

but when I try to pass the id to an href tag like this

```
<a href='ph/{{ $phs->id }}/informe/etapas'>
```

but the output is

> http://localhost:8000/ph/10/ph/10/informe/etapas

why the id prints /ph/10/ph/10/?

Comment: try using an absolute path <a href='/ph/{{$phs->id}}/informe/etapas'>

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should **name** your route:

```
Route::get('ph/{id}/informe', function ($id) {
  $ph = Ph::find($id);
  return view('ph.informe')->withphs($ph);
})->name('routename');
```

Then you should pass route name with your data which you want to pass:

```
<a href="{{ route('routename', ['data' => $phs->id]) }}">Your link</a>
```

Of course you need to adjust route name and data which you will pass.

I think that it will help you.